# Download file on computer From Rundeck

Tags: rundeck

Is it possible to download a file from a server through a script Rundeck on my personnal computer ?
Regards,
Frédéric

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

First scenario. The Rundeck server is running on your machine: just using a script with [curl](https://linux.die.net/man/1/curl) / [wget](https://linux.die.net/man/1/wget) to download the file locally (using a local path).

Second scenario. The Rundeck server isn't on your computer: just set up an HTTP/bucket server, and print the download link in the Rundeck job output.